# Cassandra size limit per partition key

Tags: java, database, cassandra, cloud, scylla

I have this table in cassandra :

```
CREATE TABLE adress (
adress_id uuid,
adress_name text,
key1 text,
key2 text,
key3 text,
key4 text,
effective_date timestamp,
value text,
active boolean,
PRIMARY KEY ((adress_id, adress_name), key1, key2, key3, key4, effective_date)
)
```

As I can understand, cassandra will distribute the data of the table adress based on the partition key which is (adress_id, adress_name).

There is a risk when I try to insert too many data where they share the same (adress_id,adress_name)..

I would like to check before inserting data, the check happen like this:

1. how many data do I already have in cassandra with the couple (adress_id, adress_name), lets suppose it's 5MO.
2. I need to check that the size of data that I'm trying to insert don't exceed the **Cassandra limit per partition key** minus the existing data in cassandra.

My question is how to query cassandra to get the **size of data** with the couple (adress_id, adress_name).
After that what is the **size limit of a partition key** in Cassandra.

Comment: You may have really big partitions (I have seen some broken setups where one partition was 60Gb), but it's better not to have them more than 100Mb. But everything really depends on what queries you're using to access your data.

Comment: @AlexOtt thank you for you answer ! any thoughts how to calculate the size of an existing partition ?

Comment: mostly by reading data & summing everything together + overhead from metadata... But I recommend to just spend more time on the data model. `nodetool tablehistograms` will give you current distribution of partition sizes

Comment: lesser the size of partition , better the performance.  if your partition is too big, Cassandra has to scan entire partition to fetch the results.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Alex Ott noted above, you should spend more time on the data model to avoid the possibility of huge partitions in the first place, by organizing your data differently, or by artificially splitting partitions to more pieces (e.g., time-series data often splits data into a separate partition each day, for example).

It is technically possible to figure out the existing size of a partition, but it will never be efficient. To understand why, you need to recall how Cassandra stores data. The content of a single partition isn't always stored in the same sstable (on-disk file) - data for the same partition may be spread across multiple files. One file may have a few rows, another file may have a few more rows, a third file may delete or modify some old rows, and so on. To figure out the length of the partition, Cassandra would need to read all this all data, merge it together, and measure the size of the result. Cassandra does **not** normally do this on writes - it just writes the new update to memory (and eventually a new sstable), without reading the old data first. This is what makes writes in Cassandra so fast - and your idea to read the entire partition before each write will drastically slow them down.

Finally while Cassandra does not handle huge partitions very well, there is no inherent reason why it never could if the developers wanted to solve this issue. The developers of the Cassandra clone Scylla a worried about this issue, and are working to improve it, but even in Scylla the handling of huge partitions isn't perfect yet. But eventually it will be. Almost - there will always be a limit for the size of a single partition (which, by definition, is stored on a single node) as the size of a single disk. This limit too may become a serious problem if your data model is really broken and you can end up with a terabyte in a single partition.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this was very helpful! 
I need to figure out a solution how to re-model the data so I don't fall in the problem of big partitions.. 
Well, considering the data model is already in production and there are too many data associated with it, then I feel like it's impossible to make the change.. any thoughts how should I process to rectify the bad data model?

Comment: That depends on your use case of course. In some use cases, most of the partitions are normal, but just a very few *bad* partitions are huge. For example, if your partitions represent users and most users have modest activity history, but just a few spambots make 1000 requests each minute. In this case you can have a *background* process to look for large partitions (before they become utterly huge) and delete them and/or blacklist their key as spam partitions so further writes don't try to write into them.